# Fourier series of piecewise function, special case

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering how to find the Fourier series piecewise functions where the interval on which each of the partial functions are defined are unequal. For example:
$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ x^2 & 1 \le x\le \pi\end{cases} $ (and let's just consider the Fourier sine series of $f$ for the sake of brevity).

What coefficient should be used before the integral of $b_n$? My guess is $1$ for $\int_0^1 \dots$, but I'm stuck with the coefficient before $\int_1^\pi \dots$. Or can I just use $\frac1\pi$ for both integrals?

I have one more questions regarding the arguments of $\sin$ in both integrals. We need $\sin(n\pi x/L)$ when working on $[-L,L]$. But since the integrals have other lengths, I'm wondering whether I can use $\sin(nx)$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Write down the general formula for the coefficients first (expressed through $f(x)$), then substitute your particular function. The only special thing for piecewise functions is that you would need to separate the integral into two parts. The $1/ \pi$ factor will stay the same

Comment: Can I use $1/\pi$ when the interval is $[0,\pi]$? Or should I first extend the function to make sure it is odd (since the question is about the sine series) on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: Wait a minute, how are you going to extend the function and use the sine series if your function is neither even nor odd? I think you should work on $[0, \pi]$ and use the full series with both sine and cosine terms

Comment: This is what I've done: $F(x) = \begin{cases} -x^2 & -\pi \le x \le  -1 \\ -x & -1 \le x \le 0 \\ x & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ x^2 & 1 \le x \le \pi \end{cases}$. Then $b_n =  \frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^{-\pi} F(x) \sin(nx)dx = \frac2\pi \int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx$. And then I separated the integral into two parts. Result: $f(x) = \frac{-2}{\pi} \sum_{n \ge 1} ( \frac{\sin n}{n^2} + (-1)^n \frac{\pi^2}{n} + \frac{2}{n^3} ((-1)^n - \cos n))\sin nx$. Which seems correct.